# How to move certain values to another column for all values that follow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a table-like dataframe with different subheadings. I want to move the values [x], [y], [z] from column x to another column for every value under [x] and above the next [] value like so:

```
0   [x]
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   [y]
5   d
6   e
7   [z]
8   f
```

to

```
0   a   [x]
1   b   [x]
2   c   [x]
3   d   [y]
4   e   [y]
5   f   [z]
6   g   [z]
```

My thinking was to split the dataframe for every value [] and then merge the dataframes after putting values [] in a column. Is there a way to do this at once?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC,

assuming your first column is called `A`

idea is to use basic filtering and `ffill`

not sure where `g` comes in your expected output.

```
df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('\['),'new_col'] = df['A']

df['new_col'] = df['new_col'].ffill()

df_new = df.loc[df['A'].str.contains('\[')==False]

print(df_new)
   A new_col
1  a     [x]
2  b     [x]
3  c     [x]
5  d     [y]
6  e     [y]
8  f     [z]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
s = df['col'].copy()
s.loc[~s.str[0].eq('[')] = pd.np.nan
df['col2'] = s.ffill()
print(df[~df['col'].str[0].eq('[')].reset_index(drop=True))
```